# java, oracle - switch databases when one is down

Tags: java, oracle

I used to have a RAC with two databases and a single cluster on them so i used jdbc thin url with cluster ip which was working fine.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host)(PORT=1521))
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service_name)))
```

But due to some reasons cluster ip is down.

So i want to connect to both the databases so i used jdbc thin url with both the hosts given as follows.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=
(LOAD_BALANCE=on)
(ADDRESS_LIST=
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host1) (PORT=1521))
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host2)(PORT=1521)))
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service_name)))
```

But using this it sometimes connects to the database sometimes throws a network error. But if i check them with individual hosts its working fine with both.

So, i need a workaround where i can switch between databases on the fly when one is down.

Comment: Do you want software to know how/when to change or not? Can you use a virtual IP address for this?

Comment: Actually i want to have some piece of java code so that it changes the databases when one is down. used virtual IP stil same error...

Comment: I think you mean you have two instances, not two databases

Comment: You need to fix your installation. You want to use the scan-ip.

Comment: In addition you might want to configure basic taf failover